# php - calling a function to send email in loop

Tags: php, phpmailer, mailtrap

I'm using PHPMailer to send multiple emails to different recipients.

To summarize what I'm trying to do here is to send emails to all the persons concerned telling them they have a task/action to do.

In this case **$actions** contains exactly 2 arrays with 2 different recipients indexed as "**action_owner**". So I'm looping through **$actions** to get both recipients

[Output of **$actions**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFG3p.png)

The problem is in my testing inbox (Mailtrap) I'm only getting 1 email instead of 2. The email content I'm getting in my inbox is from the first iteration of the loop.

As you will see in the code I tried to output the recipients I'm getting and my function to sending the emails. There's no problem with the outputs, I'm getting the recipients I want and the function **sendEmail()** is being called twice as intended.

```
case 'action':
      $actions = $_POST['action']; 
      foreach($actions as $key=>$val){
        $emailParams = [
          'to'      => [$val['action_owner']],
          'bcc'     => ['bcc@email.com'],
          'subject' => _('Subject'),
          'nc_actions'   => $val['nc_actions']
        ];
        // dump($emailParams);
        $test = $mail->sendEmail('nc/action_email', $emailParams);
        // dump($test);
      }
      die;
```

```
private function generateEmailBody(string $templateFile, array $params)
{
    // error_reporting(0);
    ob_start();
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/layouts/emails/header.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/layouts/emails/' . $templateFile . '.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/layouts/emails/footer.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}

public function sendEmail(string $templateFile, array $emailParams)
{
    if (empty($emailParams['to']) || empty($emailParams['subject'])) {
        throw new Exception('Missing required parameters for sending email');
    }

    $this->Subject = $emailParams['subject'];
    $this->Body    = $this->generateEmailBody($templateFile, $emailParams);

    foreach ($emailParams['to'] as $to) {
        $this->addAddress($to);

        if (!empty($emailParams['bcc'])) {
            foreach ($emailParams['bcc'] as $bcc) {
                $this->AddBCC($bcc);
            }
        }

        $this->send();
        $this->ClearAllRecipients();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `require_once` means the file, once included, can't be included again. So I suspect you just get a repeat of the same content you required the first time. This isn't really a sensible way to build it...use functions, and/or a proper templating engine.

Comment: @ADyson This was the problem, the 2nd email couldn't be sent because the body was empty after sending the first email. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is that you are adding the recipients using the addAddress() method within the loop, but you are not clearing the recipients after each iteration.

To fix this, you should move the addAddress() method outside of the loop and use the ClearAllRecipients() method to clear the recipients after each iteration.

Here's the updated code:

```php
case 'action':
    $actions = $_POST['action']; 
    foreach($actions as $key=>$val){
        $emailParams = [
            'to'      => [$val['action_owner']],
            'bcc'     => ['bcc@email.com'],
            'subject' => _('Subject'),
            'nc_actions'   => $val['nc_actions']
        ];
        // Add recipients outside of the loop
        $mail->addAddress($val['action_owner']);
        $test = $mail->sendEmail('nc/action_email', $emailParams);
        // Clear recipients after each iteration
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    }
    die;

public function sendEmail(string $templateFile, array $emailParams)
{
    //...
    foreach ($emailParams['to'] as $to)
    {
        // Remove addAddress() method from here
        if (!empty($emailParams['bcc']))
        {
            foreach ($emailParams['bcc'] as $bcc)
            {
                $this->AddBCC($bcc);
            }
        }
        $this->send();
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Also take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).